# Как вычесть от каждого элемента матрицы некоторое число n?

Tags: pascal

Мне дана матрица А(10х1).

```
90 
144 
210 
225 
315 
270 
195 
186 
200 
150
```

Нужно вычесть от каждого элемента число 198,5 и вывести в новый массив В. Подскажите код на Паскале

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала массив B должен быть REAL типа!
ну а далее все просто.
переменные сам пропиши в VAR

```
begin
for i:=0 to 10 do
   b[i]:=a[i]-198.5;

for i:=0 to 10 do
   writeln(b[i]);

readln;
end.
```